# Cant understand annotation propagation for lambdas in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

According to official documentation - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#lambdas
there is an approach for introspect a lambda function for annotations searching. But i cant find any examples for this approach

But `invoke()` method does not provide any context, because it is just a directive for function evaluating

How to properly find any annotation placed right before lambda function? Should I implement any javaagent (AOP) for this solution?

Example of code was taken right from official documentation

`val f = @Suspendable { Fiber.sleep(10) }`

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need exactly. Documentation explains how annotations can be applied to lambdas and what does it do as a result. Otherwise, this isn't different than using annotations in any other place.

Comment: I need an access to this annotation in runtime.
Example - a function that receives varargs of lambdas and execute only lambdas with some annotation

Comment: I was intrigued and did a bit of testing. It seems that the following will return what you want: `f::class.java.methods.first { it.name == "invoke" && it.returnType == Void.TYPE }.annotations`. I'm guessing there should be a better way though

Comment: I also experimented a little and I think `f.reflect()!!.annotations` should work. But it doesn't. Maybe this is because `reflect()` is still experimental.

Comment: @broot, I think you are quite right. I'll report this behaviour to JB team